# webinterface: Get Bad Request when clicking "URL to file:"

Tags: artifactory

if I use the webinterface to download a file via the "URL to file" link
I get an error saying "HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request" (in JSON Format).

Tried Firefox and Chrome. Artifactory is 7.25.7 on Ubuntu 18.

Anyone an idea?

Best Regards Sven

Comment: are you using any reverse proxy on top of Artifactory? If so, bypass the reverse proxy and use the IP and port to download the file. It seems an issue with the reverse proxy configured.

Comment: I already tried to bypass the proxy with direct IP and port 8082 but still the same result.

Comment: A Normal curl -O https://artifacry-server.com/file/blablab.h for exmaple works

Comment: any errors in the artifactory logs when you get the URL to file?

Comment: If I try to download for e.h. a *.dll file I only se this:
    2021-09-27T08:37:16.819Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [4fbe5f151a5f4f17] [                              ] [main                ] - [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:8046/artifactory
    2021-09-27T08:37:16.858Z [jffe ] [INFO ] [2c78913fdc94f807] [                              ] [main                ] - [HPM] Proxy created: /  -> http://localhost:8046/artifactory

in the console.log but no error messages...?

Comment: can you share the url here using which you tried to download the artifact by masking the IP?

Comment: Used this one (without nginx)

http://192.168.100.100:8082/artifactory/repo-local/path/filename.dll

Comment: is it working now or same issue? did you tried curl or UI? Can you test with wget as well?

Comment: "wget" works, "curl -O" works, only pasting the URL to a browser fails.

Comment: do you notice any errors in the browsers developer tools console output?

Comment: Also no errors in the browser console. It is reading the error page with no errors. I also tried with version 7.27.6 but still I get this error.

Comment: The error page says: `
    {
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "message": "<!doctype html><html lang=\"en\"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type=\"text/css\">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1></body></html>"
    }
  ]
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding
"org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true"
to your app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties file and then restart artifactory.
I've got the exact same issue right now on version 7.23.3.  Apparently there is a bug that the slash encoding is not getting set for some reason.  Everything works fine except for downloading via the GUI, and pulling down NPM scoped packages.
I've had a ticket open with jfrog about this for a while now.  There is a setting you should be able to put in your yaml file, but that unfortunately doesn't work either.  Hopefully they can sort this out as its a step you have to remember to do post upgrade since the above change gets removed as part of that process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after upgrading the binaries from Artifactory 7.24.3 to 7.27.15 and although I didn't need to add in `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true`, apparently adding it to the bottom of the catalina.properties file just fixed this problem for me. Still don't get why it doesn't get picked up in the YAML file or why it worked before the upgrade.

I did determine that the reason for the 400 error is due to the percent sign in the API v1 endpoint that gets called is getting encoded, so stuff like %2F gets called on as %252F.

Also, if you're running Nginx in front of Artifactory, you still might need the following to make your npm work:

```
        location ~ ^/artifactory/ {
            proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:8081$uri;
        }
```

Comment: Adding "org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH=true" to my app/artifactory/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties fixed it for me in artifactory 7.35.1